# Transform curl to open-uri in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, open-uri

I have a curl line like this:

```
curl https://api.paymill.com/v2.1/checksums -u 'private_user_key' -d 'checksum_type=paypal' -d 'amount=4200'
```

and I want to transform it into a open-uri call like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
open("https://api.paymill.com/v2.1/checksums", http_basic_authentication: ['private_user_key'])
```

Works so far, but how do I include the -d data-attributes like -d 'checksum_type=paypal' -d 'amount=4200'?

Thanks, Andreas

Comment: I would suggest that you look at a gem called curb.  I had the same issues in the past - will allow you to use the exact same curl line within your application

Comment: @phoffer, I've tried to replace -d by attribute like data: {'checksum_type=paypal', 'amount=4200'} or d: {..} as it worked for -u and http_basic_authentication: ... but none of this worked for me

Comment: @MageeWorld Thanks, but I try to avoid using a gem for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll be better off using `Net::HTTP` directly (instead of open-uri, which is just a convenience wrapper). This gives you more control over the request being made.

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI("https://api.paymill.com/v2.1/checksums")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth("username", "password")
request.set_form_data('checksum_type' => 'paypal', 'amount' => 4200)
response = http.request(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some very good Net::HTTP examples includung form requests here: http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html